# Testing without the "Bloatware"

Tags: testing, angular-dart

I've been trying to write some tests for an existing AngularDart application and I have to say it is an awful experience so far: documentation is practically non-existing (still as draft with big chunks missing) and I feel kind of left hanging.

I want to simply unit-test the functions I have in a component. No need for the whole test-bed initialization or anything of the sorts. Why? Because is faster and I don't want to test the presentation layer, just my logic...

Anyway here is a trimmed down example:

**app_component.dart**

```dart
    import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

    @Component(
      selector: 'my-app',
      styleUrls: ['app_component.css'],
      templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
    )
    class AppComponent extends OnInit {
      bool isValid = false;
    
      @override
      void ngOnInit() {
        isValid = true;
      }
    }
```

**app_component.html**

```html
    <h1>My First AngularDart App</h1>
```

**app_component.css**

```css
    :host {
        /* This is equivalent of the 'body' selector of a page. */
    }
```

**app_test**

```dart
    import 'package:my_app/app_component.dart';
    import 'package:test/test.dart';
    
    void main() {
      var component = AppComponent();
    
      test('initial value should be false', () {
        expect(component.isValid, false);
      });
    
      test('value after init should be true', () {
        component.ngOnInit();
    
        expect(component.isValid, true);
      });
    }
```

As you can see there is **absolutely** nothing fancy here.
If I run the tests like this:

```
    pub run build_runner test -- -p chrome
```

then everything works like a charm.
However if I try to run like:

```
    pub run build_runner test (or pub run test)
```

I get a bunch of errors due to, what I am guessing, some web dependencies:

```
    Unable to spawn isolate: test/app_test.dart:3:8: Error: Error when reading 
    
    'lib/app_component.template.dart': No such file or directory
    
    import 'package:chess_dart/app_component.template.dart' as ng;
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular_test-2.3.0/lib/src/frontend/bed.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular_test-2.3.0/lib/src/frontend/fixture.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular-5.3.1/lib/src/core/application_ref.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular-5.3.1/lib/src/core/testability/testability.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' show Element;
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular_test-2.3.0/lib/src/bootstrap.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular-5.3.1/lib/src/core/linker/app_view_utils.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html' show DocumentFragment, NodeTreeSanitizer;
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular-5.3.1/lib/src/runtime/dom_events.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular-5.3.1/lib/src/bootstrap/modules.dart:6:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
           ^
    ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/angular-5.3.1/lib/src/common/directives/ng_class.dart:1:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
    import 'dart:html';
             ^
    00:01 +0 -1: Some tests failed.
```

Can someone shed some light into this? I want to run my tests on the CI and if possible I want to avoid the hassle of having to install a browser on docker just to run the tests.

Thanks

Comment: @fdtiz Hi, yous work with angularDart so can you give me an advice please ? I'd like to learn a new frontend framework but I'm confused between AngularDart and Angular (typescript). In fact I'd like to work with dart language that's why I tend to AngularDart but I find it not very used all over the world and no enough tutorials exist. What do you suggest , can you give me an advice please ?

Comment: Personally I would recommend AngularJS (typescript) since like you said there is more resources out there. Dart is awesome and has a lot of features built-in where in JS you would need libraries. Dart also has less problems as a language than JS (IMHO). However I would also recommend you to check React out. It is lighterweight, i.e. you don't have some of the luxury features from Angular. But I find it offers better testing and I had really nice experiences using it

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll start with angularJs so.

Answer (score 0):

Running `pub run build_runner test` without any parameters will [always run the test in Dart VM](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/tree/master/pkgs/test#running-tests).

Which is why you are looking at a bunch of missing dependency

```
import 'dart:html';
           ^
```

There is no `dart:html` in Dart VM.

There is one thing you can do to avoid this, by adding a `@TestOn("browser")`  to the head of your `*_test.dart` file. This will tell test-runner to run the tests in the file in the browser. After doing this, you should be able to use the command `pub run build_runner test` to run all your test.

But. This does not resolve your trouble to run this in CI. I would say it is fair to require a browser to run a test meant to be run only in a browser.

Comment: I agree with requiring a browser for tests that should run in a browser. But I don't see this as being the case here.
I am testing a property of a dart class and nothing more. I think it is fair enough to say that it should be possible to run tests without having to "spin up" browsers and such